# Amazon WS EC2 Alternative

Tags: svn, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am looking for an alternative to Amazon EC2 Web Service in order to use an instance to running an SVN Server. Because AWS is not free I'm looking a free alternative service.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembla has good Subversion hosting.

Comment: What does Assembla offer?

Answer (score 1):

Have you been using AWS for longer than 12 months? If not, you can use EC2 micro-instances for free. See the [free tier FAQS](http://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/) for more info.

If you are not eligible for AWS's free tier, then [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=dbb0c9916a29) offers 512MB VPS's for $5 per month.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the problem with Amazon is that I have to register my credit card, absolutely...and I don't want to register it!

Answer (score 1):

Is this for a free/open source repo? Or for your own private/commercial code?

If its for a FOSS account, you might just as well skip SVN and go to GitHub (there's a bit of a learning curve, but it seems to be the way forward for version control).

If you are wanting to host a commercial product, then I'm sure you can afford the $5 per month that a low-end VPS would cost.